# Override default ModelBinder in Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I want to override the default model binder of my Web Api project. How can do this?

**More Description:**

What I do now is this:

```
// I defined a custom model binder 
public class EmptyStringToNullModelBinder : IModelBinder

//Before all my parameters in actions I use it
public IHttpActionResult PostSomething([FromUri(BinderType = typeof(EmptyStringToNullModelBinder))]string text = null,...)
```

There are a lot of string parameters in my whole project that assigned with this attribute. It's a little bit ugly. I want to tell to Web Api that "Use this attribute as default for all my string parameters".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ModelBinderProvider` was designed to cover such scenario. This abstract class has the only method:

```
public abstract IModelBinder GetBinder(HttpConfiguration configuration, Type modelType);
```

`GetBinder` should return implementation of `IModelBinder` for the given type or `null` if the type could not be processed with current binder.

Here is a generic implementation of `ModelBinderProvider` that maps a type to a binder:

```
public class CustomModelBinderProvider<TModel> : ModelBinderProvider
{
    private readonly IModelBinder binder;

    public CustomModelBinderProvider(IModelBinder binder)
    {
        this.binder = binder;
    }

    public override IModelBinder GetBinder(HttpConfiguration configuration, Type modelType)
    {
        return modelType == typeof(TModel) ? binder : null;
    }
}
```

In `WebApiConfig.Register()` method set up this model binder for `String` type:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // ...

    var binderProvider = new CustomModelBinderProvider<string>(new EmptyStringToNullModelBinder());
    config.Services.Insert(typeof(ModelBinderProvider), 0, binderProvider);
}
```

Now in your controller you don't need to specify a binder type, `EmptyStringToNullModelBinder` will be used for string types:

```
public IHttpActionResult PostSomething([FromUri]string text = null,...)
```